# Split String from database in mvc

Tags: c#, split

I have a class like this:

```
public class User
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Module { get; set; }
}
```

For `Module` I want to set split it when reach a certain length, example like

```
:Maths/English/Physics/Chemistry,Maths/English/Physics/Chemistry
```

I want to get these results:

```
Maths/English/Physics/Chemistry
Maths/English/Physics/Chemistry
```

I have tried this method, but it doesn't work:

```
string input = Module;
string[] result = input.Split(new string[] { " , " }, StringSplitOptions.None);
```

Comment: Could you please clarify: 1) what do you mean saying it doesn't work? 2) where do you need to put resulting strings? 3) Do you want to only split strings that contain the same substring (like in your example the same substring is repeated twice)?

Comment: as it still remain as the same row,any substring reaches a certain length will split to second row

Comment: So it will still be a `string`, but with a newline ? Or you want a `string [] Modules` ? This is really not clear

Comment: what second row means?you are talking about showing module data in UI side ?

Comment: yes, with a new line. I will try to figure it out and make it clearer, Thank You

Comment: Alright, and what is the rule to break the `Module` into a newline ?

Comment: Try splitting on `","` instead of `" , "` ?

Answer (score 0):

May be this work using Regex instead of string.split try this

```
  string value = @":Maths/English/Physics/Chemistry/Maths/English/Physics/Chemistry";

  // Get a collection of matches.
  MatchCollection matches = Regex.Matches(value, @"Maths/English/Physics/Chemistry");

  // Use foreach-loop.
  foreach (Match match in matches)
  {
      // DO you jobs for each "Maths/English/Physics/Chemistry"
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

I think that you want to split your 8 segments into items where you can define the length of each item. Here is a simple version of code to do that.

```
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var outputs = SplitIntoParts("Maths/English/Physics/Chemistry/Maths/English/Physics/Chemistry", 4);
        foreach(var output in outputs)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(output);
        }
    }

    private static List<string> SplitIntoParts(string input, int itemLength)
    {
        var result = new List<string>();
        var splittedValues = input.Split('/');
        for (var i = 0; i < splittedValues.Length; i++)
        {
            var item = string.Empty;
            if (i % itemLength > 0)
            {
                item = result[result.Count - 1];
            }
            item += splittedValues[i];
            if (i % itemLength < itemLength - 1)
            {
                item += "/";
            }
            if (i % itemLength == 0)
            {
                result.Add(item);
            }
            else
            {
                result[result.Count - 1] = item;
            }
        }
        return result;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Something along this lines would work

```
 string modulesJoined =":Maths/English/Physics/Chemistry,Maths/English/Physics/Chemistry";
 string [] res = modulesJoined.Split(',');
 string module = string.Join("\n", res);
 module = module.TrimStart(':');
```